# Changing the color of a "-" symbol within the align environment

Tags: color, align, ieeetran

I need to highlight a "-" sign together with the term next to it in an equation which is inside the align environment.

In principle, I need something like this:

[image]

but with the minus sign highlighted in the same way as the "b" term.

The problem is that when I try to include the minus in the color-changing command, the spacing is screwed up:

[image]

Using `IEEEtrantools` instead of LaTeX's plain `align` doesn't help either. Anyone knows of any clean solution to this?

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\begin{document}

Test:

\begin{align*}
a-b&=a-b\\
a+b&=a+b
\end{align*}

Test with color 1:

\begin{align*}
a{\color{ocre}-b}&=a-b\\
a+b&=a+b
\end{align*}

Test with color 2:

\begin{align*}
a-{\color{ocre}b}&=a-b\\
a+b&=a+b
\end{align*}

Test with IEEE:

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
a{\color{ocre}-b}&=&a-b\\
a+b&=&a+b
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what is happening when `-b` is put inside braces is that the minus is being
interpreted as a unary rather than a binary minus, since it has nothing
(as detectable by tex) on its left side.  to remedy that, it's sufficient
to insert an empty group, `{}`, to its left:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\begin{document}

Test:
\begin{align*}
a-b&=a-b\\
a+b&=a+b
\end{align*}

Test with color 1:
\begin{align*}
a{\color{ocre}{}-b}&=a-b\\
a+b&=a+b
\end{align*}

Test with IEEE:
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
a{\color{ocre}{}-b}&=&a-b\\
a+b&=&a+b
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

**edit:** another, even simpler, workaround, is to simply adjust the scope of the group:

```
{a\color{ocre}-b}&=&a-b
```

that works for this case, where the colored portion ends at the end of the cell (before the `&`). if non-colored material follows, that would need to be taken into account.  thanks to @Manuel for the suggestion in a comment to his answer.

Answer (score 6):

For this kind of things you need `\begingroup .. \endgroup`. If you use `{..}` LaTeX treats it as a `\mathord{..}`. So this should do

```
\begingroup\color{ocre}-b\endgroup
```

May be you prefer a macro; I don't know if this has any big disadvantages, though.

```
\newcommand\mathcolor[2]{\begingroup\color{#1}#2\endgroup}
..
a \mathcolor{ocre}{- b}
```

Comment: I'm just curious, for the *pro* people, what's the reason why `\textcolor` is `{\color{..}..}` rather than `\begingroup\color{..}..\endgroup`?

Comment: i hadn't registered this difference between the `\begingroup ... \endgroup` and `{ ... }` forms of input.  (thanks for pointing it out.)  many people find the verbosity of the commands disrupting in input like this, and many editors brace-match, but don't match the commands, making a difference in the complexity of debugging. so they prefer the braces for that reason.  (i'm in that category.)  there's a simple workaround for that, though, as i've shown in my answer.

Comment: Another workaround is put everything into a group, and then change whenever you want: `{a \color{ocre} - b}`. That way you have exactly the same input, just the first `{` displaced enough to the left.